# How to add Advanced Search form in Pages on homepage in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms-pages, advanced-search

I am trying to add advanced search form as a block in Pages, but the following code is not working?

> {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
>   template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml"}}

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Matus, did my solution work ? if yes you can tick left check as accepted solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change block class for Advance form.

It should be:

> {{block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml"}}

on each `phtml`, block class is defined like:

[image]

If you need to customize `phtml`, copy it from:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/form.phtml

Comment: Welcome @Marus :)

Comment: for me it's showing but 

but it's redirecting to wrong url 
http://domain/cms/index/result/?name=&sku=&description=&short_description=&price[from]=&price[to]=&color=