# how to add link for advance search in magento 2 home page default theme?

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, advanced-search

i followed this answer

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258463/73525

step 1:

`{{block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml"}}`

i did it's showing in home page (advanced search)

but
step 2:

If you need to customize phtml, copy it from:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml
```

**where i can copy to 
my default theme in magento**

in my folders

> app/design/Magento after this no folder available

how i can do step 2

(i'm using magento luma theme)

Answer (score 1):

Add Following Code in default.xml layout of theme

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-footer-link">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">[Add Label]</argument>
      <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">[Add Link]</argument>
     </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

you can add `default.xml` in `app/design/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/`

Comment: i don't have any folder 
in

app/design/frontend/magento/

Comment: please check my edited answer

Comment: what i do this  [add lable]  [add link]

Comment: add Label like `Advance Search` and Link like `catalogsearch/advanced/`

Comment: not working....

should i add any registration.php

Comment: or theme.xml .......

Comment: create child theme. refer  [this](https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-child-theme-in-magento-2/) link

Comment: why child theme  i added luma/Magento_catelogadvancedsearch

Comment: Because of you don't have custom theme so base on it you need to create child theme. If you change default luma theme and after upgrade magento your changes will be remove. better solution is to create child theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not create custom theme yet , but you want changes on defualt luma theme

Please co here and create customization on it.

For your project : `project/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/`

For Advanced Search : `project/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_AdvancedSearch`

Or please can u create a custom theme on :`project/app/design/frontend/` this folder..

Answer (score 0):

in Default luma theme Advanced Search link already available in the footer. see in screenshot https://prnt.sc/o5a9ke

If you need customized that form you need to override file. For that, you need to create a theme new theme and override file in your created theme.